# How to make a calculation on the list of HashMaps in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, set

I currently have the following sorted set of maps of data:

```
[
   {"name":"john", "date":2015, "status":"success"},
   {"name":"john", "date":2013, "status":"fail"},
   {"name":"chris", "date":2013, "status":"success"},
   {"name":"john", "date":2012, "status":"fail"},
   {"name":"john", "date":2009, "status":"success"},
   {"name":"chris", "date":2007, "status":"fail"},
   {"name":"john", "date":2005, "status":"fail"},
]
```

I'm trying to calculate the failure duration for each of the names until `2022`. Status for each name is in failure until the next success status.

So, let's say for the name `john`, it was failed on `2005`, next success was `2009`, which means 4 years of failure. Then it got failed again on `2012`, and again on `2013`, which overall until `2015` would be 3 years of failure. Combining them would result in 7 years for `john`.

With the same logic, for `chris` we have 6 years of failure.

I'm stuck in the implementation of this. Does anyone have an efficient solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a `Record` class for each entry

```java
public class Record {
    public String name;
    public Integer date;
    public String status;

    public Record(String name, Integer date, String status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

You can use `Stream` API to achieve your goals

```java
public static Map<String, Integer> useStream(List<Record> records) {
    return records.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.name))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> {
            Integer[] lastFail = new Integer[]{null};
            return e.getValue().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(r -> r.date))
                .mapToInt(t -> {
                    if (t.status.equals("fail") && lastFail[0] == null) {
                        lastFail[0] = t.date;
                    } else if (t.status.equals("success") && lastFail[0] != null) {
                        int last = lastFail[0];
                        lastFail[0] = null;
                        return t.date - last;
                    }
                    return 0;
                })
                .sum();
        }));
}
```

Or you can use better [`Seq`](https://github.com/wolray/seq-java/blob/master/README.md) API with smoother code

```java
public static Map<String, Integer> useSeq(List<Record> records) {
    return Seq.of(records)
        .groupBy(r -> r.name)
        .toList()
        .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> {
            Integer[] lastFail = new Integer[]{null};
            return Seq.of(e.getValue())
                .sortBy(r -> r.date)
                .sumInt(t -> {
                    if (t.status.equals("fail") && lastFail[0] == null) {
                        lastFail[0] = t.date;
                    } else if (t.status.equals("success") && lastFail[0] != null) {
                        int last = lastFail[0];
                        lastFail[0] = null;
                        return t.date - last;
                    }
                    return 0;
                });
        });
}
```

Both of these methods result as {chris=6, john=7}